# OMNeT++ compiles and links every time I Run/Debug

Tags: omnet++

I'm not changing the code. I just click Run/Debug, and OMNeT++ compiles and links, and takes forever to run. I'm new to OMNeT++, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: OMNeT++ is just a tool. Which project are you running?

Comment: @JulianHeinovski I am running some examples from INET 3.4.6

Comment: Which OMNeT++ version are you using? You can also run a simulation by right-clicking on the omnetpp.ini configuration file and select run as -> OMNeT++ simulation. And compile just the project via right-clicking the project and selecting compile. The menu buttons typically lead to a compilation of all open projects, that's not necessary when you (for example) have a separated project that only references to INET and you only have changes in your project and leave INET untouched. Also check if your run/debug configuration maybe cleans (make clean) your projects before they are compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to run the example:  `/inet/examples/ieee80211.`

For this you may right click `/inet/examples/ieee80211/omnetpp.ini` , from the context menu that appears you choose "Run As" then "OMNET++ Simulation".

Unfortunately in your case, this process starts to rebuild the complete code of `/inet`. To fix it, instead of choosing **"OMNET++ Simulation"** from context menu, select **"Run Configurations.."**.

A dialog will appear, by default contents of **"Main"** tab are displayed. Scroll down the "Main" tab window to end, there will be a link **"More>>"**, so click it. **"Advanced"** section on the same window will appear. Below this section will be another section **"Build before launch"** and then from the menu of "Projects to build:" select "This project only". Click "Apply" then "Run" this time your problem would have solved. Enjoy :)